# Falcon Circus, Chapter 0: The Decision

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual, story, steganography

### [The Prologue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69145/falcon-circus-prologue-the-twins)

Lycan pouted. I guess he was expecting his little riddle to be hard. Lichen didn't have a change in expression, although this doesn't surprise you. The red twin glared at you for another second before throwing something at you and trudging away, muttering, "I even did drafts, like Lichen said... I'm never listening to him again!"

The green twin watched his brother leave before turning to see what item you acquired. His eyes widened for a second, but returned to its gloomy state. He didn't try to take the item from you. Lichen looked away from you and mumbled, *"Don't lose it."* You look at the key. "Well... that's a red flag if I've ever seen one- an unknown, seemingly important item- a key, no less!- given to be by a child *clown?* No thank you, Lichen, but you can have it ba-"
The boy was gone. Huh.

---

$\hskip2.5in$You've acquired: Brass Key

### $\hskip2.5in$[image: brass key]

It left a bit of a sour taste in your mouth to have made that poor kid angry, but you had bigger problems to worry about now; when you had entered, you noticed how dimly lit the place was. You hadn't really paid attention to your surroundings since the twins startled you, but a good look reveals that the place is pretty empty. Something about the key is unnerving... you feel as though you've opened a can of worms that should have been left closed.

[image: circus entryway]

There is a signpost in the center with what appear to be directions- it's a shame they're written in some odd language. Bah. You don't need a stupid signpost anyway. There seem to be doors going in all directions, save for the way you came. Where will you go?

$\hskip1.4in$[image: go left][image: forward][image: backward][image: right]

---

### tdlr;

Past this point (including tldr;) is instructions, and is not part of the puzzle.
You solved the first riddle and have finished the prologue. Now, you must begin the first chapter for your journey. You must choose which door you wish to go through. Some doors are much easier to solve than others- yes, multiple doors have answers in this puzzle. The first correct passcode provided is the door we will go through together, unless you all decide to solve every passcode and make an executive decision on which direction you'd like to go. You are the ones leading this dynamic puzzle.

Welcome to the Falcon Circus.

### [The Predator](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69491/falcon-circus-chapter-1-the-predator)

Comment: EVERYONE JOIN CHAT TO DISCUSS

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81482/falcon-circus-discussion

Comment: A door has been solved, and a door has been chosen. The Predator awaits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to start off by linking some of the images here: 
If you click left, you get

> An imgur sequence jwg72, leading [to an apparent riddle and tentacle monster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwg72.png). Since we know the answer is TAD_, we have to find the number that is not mentioned. From below, it's not 9; further, 50 is written on the right wall. From the prequel puzzle, the address 318 is featured; further there are 2 twins (the word two is written in the prequel). The URL for left door contains 7 and 2; the URL for right door contains 6. This leaves 4, so is the code for the left door TAD4?

If you click back,

> [Back is not an option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5K5j.gif)

If you click forward, you get

> [This riddle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYplb.png)

If you click right, you get

> [a bunch of weird voices in a cave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coc6J.png)

My first thought is

> go right, since one of the voices is talking about a key and we might be able to use it; I'm not appreciating having to face off against any of the creatures of the deep behind doors 1 and 2....

Comment: What do you think the voice means by "roses, grapes"

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. But roses, grapes sounds much more fun than giant scary monsters

Comment: Possibly, but doesn't every door have a riddle we need to solve to move on?

Comment: rot 13 (Gur grag pbybef ybbx yvxr gubfr bs ebfrf naq tencrf)

Comment: @iiiidk, updated my answer for the left door.......

Comment: @El-Guest And you've won the ability to choose if you'd like to go through that door or not :)

Comment: @iiiidk let's do it! I'm ready for some calamari :)

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing in my thoughts:

> The key, when viewed here, seems to have 7 tallies. When clicked on, it has 8. It also has the letters "TAD" on it

Also

> When zoomed in, the main picture shows some sort of claw mark through the right facing sign? No idea what this means, just throwing this observation in there for smarter people

Also

> Note the indentation when you click the forward sign. This might be important.

Also, this image flashes briefly when the center image is clicked:

> [[image: the room through the key]

Comment: Oh thanks, didn't know how to do that

Comment: rot13(Vg ybbxf yvxr gurer ner fbzr gnoyrf bs qvssrerag fvmrf arkg gb gur qbbe fgenvtug nurnq)

Answer (score 1):

Compiling some of my observations

Left:

> The creature seems to be releasing some dark liquid like oil (seen in the gif with sign board). Similar greasy dark liquid is on the key (after you click on the key image). The tally is 8, so is the creature an octopus?

Straight:

> There is indentation. Maybe all sentences at the same indent level need to be read together? Ex: I want them all. In order. (It's asking for something to be put in order)

Right:

> The tent colors look like those of roses and grapes

Gif with signboard:

> It looks like there are gift boxes of different sizes and one fence kind of thing (or cage with an animal in it) next to the door straight ahead

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer/thoughts:

> Clicking on the left arrow brings us to a picture with a five-character string, "jwg72". Changing the filename of the .png to that string brings us to another picture. The picture says "I am the letters that let you see. I am the number you never see. A four length code is all I need." Clicking on the key image above takes you to an altered key image with the text "You can see." The string TAD is visible on the key. Perhaps these are the letters that "let us see". The number you never see could be 0. The tally marks on the key also changes from 7 to 8 between the pictures. Maybe that's important.

Answer (score 0):

Could the code for the lefthand door be:

> TAD0
>
> The key shows the letters "TAD", and the number 0 does not appear anywhere.

EDIT:

> I think the code is TAD9
>  We know it is TAD
>  And all the numbers except 3,4, and 9 clearly show up in either the urls of images or in the pictures themselves. There are 3 directions to go in, and four signs, so we are left with 9?

Comment: [He answers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzqMf.png)