# Falcon Circus, Chapter 1: The Predator

Tags: riddle, visual, story

### [The Decision](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69330/falcon-circus-chapter-1-the-decision)

With three doors to choose from and three riddles to solve, you decide to stick to one. Of the three, the left door seemed the shortest and easiest... and indeed it was. You walk up to the door and say the passcode, "TAD4". The door opens.

Knowing full well how menacing your surroundings became when you looked through the eye of the key, you refrain from using it. Some sort of monster guarded the left door, but if you can't see him then he isn't there, right? Right?

[image: the room]

You enter the room, but fail to see anything; it's pitch black. Creaking noises can be heard above and in front of you. You hear a squelch, and a rough voice begins to speak. "news.... news! bREaking news! he's here, he's come!" it chides. Something cold slides across your cheek in the darkness. "now there, now there. don't you? Pretty? yes!" Whatever is speaking slithers close to your ear and touches your neck, sending a chill down your spine. Your feet grow cold.

Suddenly, the creature shrieks and recoils away. You grab your neck, using the warmth from your hand to heat it up. The key glows a dull yellow. Why can you see it in the pitch black? "fine! fine!" it squeals. "a puzzLe, yes! i yield! no, we stAy! CEase!" The creature thrashes in the darkness, and you hear banging as it collides with objects in the room. This thing seems absolutely crazy... you're beginning to regret hastily choosing a door.

It screams again, and you take the chance to hold up your key for light. The creature's eyes illuminate against the key's rays.

[image: he sees]

It stares at the key for a brief moment before turning away. plunging you back into darkness. You hear a shuffling noise, then light sobbing in the far corner.
"i don't want to die."
So far nothing has *really* been dangerous, and this whimpering creature has begun to tear at your heartstrings. You take a step forward, and it hisses. "i will. i aM not smart, i am not bravE. white, red, green, yellow: black cannot." It doesn't seem to be directing its conversation to you. You hear more squelching noises, and the parts of the room become visible.
"he trusts him."
"enough. enough! answer the riddle!"

[image: the darkness recedes]

You recoil in confusion. So many things have just happened in so little time... what is going on with this guy?! The creature is growing increasingly agitated. You've got to think fast; the black sludge oozes to and fro, covering and uncovering words.

$\hskip1.5in$[image: left][image: forward][image: backward][image: right]

---

### tldr;

The first solver of The Decision has chosen to go through the left door. The key revealed it to be the lair of some kind of monster, though we have not yet found out what it looks like. The creature seems to have something wrong with it mentally, and you want to get out of this room as quickly as possible. Solve its riddle and choose a direction to go.

---

A direction has been chosen, and decision has been made. Listening to the voice, you continue your journey.

### [The Wise](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/falcon-circus-chapter-2-the-wise)

Comment: [The chat room for this series](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81482/falcon-circus-discussion)

Comment: Why are there two chapter 1?

Comment: The prologue allowed you to meet two important characters. The first "chapter" let you choose how you will start your chapter. This is the chapter that has been chosen. The next member you meet will be "Chapter 2". @LeppyR64

Comment: The capital letters seem to say "relace me".

Comment: Correction, capital letters seem to say "replace me".  Maybe the snake is the blue letters in the images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **If you change the brightness of the first image you get this.**
>  [image]

> **Second Image that is the same as the first** 
>  [image]

> **Third Image**
> [image]

So,

> I'm not sure, but do you go backwards and use sparrow as a pass-code?

Comment: With only one trick in the book, you've caught him red-handed. As you've found both the riddle and the hidden answer, what is your decision? (solve the riddle, use the hidden answer, choose a direction)

Comment: I will take a look :-D

Comment: Following the directions- decision noted. A check mark for you, and a change in the story to follow!

Comment: That was fast! :)

Comment: @nikki Yep yep! A creature not in the right mind? Easy peasy to defeat. (Truth be told, he was added to let more people affect the story.)

Comment: Damn, that was fast. Nice catch with the brightnesses, I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 3):

First look

> I see that the cage thingy that was a silhouette in the 'Decision' stage of the puzzle is present in right top corner

Answer (score 1):

#### Additional findings

I found a few other clues here.

> If you adjust the brightness of the LEFT image, you get:
>  [image: left]  
>  And for the RIGHT image:
>  [image: right]
>  This one leads us to a key:
>  [image: yGQPD]
>  It's got XOT written on the key and W on the tag. However since the symbol on the tag is mirrored vertically compared to the first key we had, the W is probably an M instead.