# Falcon Circus, Chapter 3: The Jungle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, visual, story

### [The Wise](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/69576/falcon-circus-chapter-2-the-wise)

You get up and dust yourself off. Pushing extra leaves and vines out of the way, the sign reads, "THIS WAY! THAT WAY! NO WAY? YES WAY!" You let out a big sigh. Oh boy. There was one door in the beginning that seemed to have multiple voices contradicting each other... you look at the flyer for a hint as to what the creatures look like.

$\hskip2.5in$[image: updated flyer]

Huh. That's strange. You could have sworn the flyer looked different before... whatever. You point out each member. "Twins... Snake... Lalia... ah-ha! These little gremlin-looking things must be the creatures I'm looking for." With a target acquired, you set out on your journey.

$\hskip0.3in$[image: beginning room]
$\hskip1.4in$[image: left][image: forward][image: back][image: right]

---

Hint 1:

> Indeed, you have oriented yourself in this great expanse. Three dead ends and three creatures to rule the jungle. Each has left a message for you. Quite unfulfilling riddles, no? I suppose children aren't very good at riddles; *they also aren't good at numbers or directions*. Perhaps they need some guidance in their life.

Comment: [The chat room for this series](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81482/falcon-circus-discussion)

Answer (score 5):

> I kept following the links and there are way too many to mention here. But I noticed that at the end of Left, you reach Forward. Towards the end of one of the paths from Right, you reach Left, and then Forward. But the other path... I'm not sure if I didn't enter the code correctly or it just leads nowhere.
>  Back leads to something that looks like the tent.
> I need to go back and check again...

Also

> There is one creature missing from the original poster. Was that King?

Map:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqUXa.jpg

Should we

> write the map as some sort of code? For example, one of the comments can be found in "B2" for 2 steps backward

Comment: For the path you think you didn't enter the code correctly, try using a lowercase "k" instead of the uppercase "K" shown in the picture.

Comment: I meant the code rot 13(qBLWR) found in rot 13(uggcf://v.fgnpx.vzthe.pbz/3jaik.cat)

Comment: Oh, that's because rot 13(gur yrggre vf n Q abg na B).

Comment: Drawing out a map is highly advised for this post :) You are correct to think that some paths double back or lead to different locations.

Comment: Ohh! Thanks @lovemathboy. And I will try to make one map!

Comment: I can confirm that your map is contains all the places in the jungle. :^)

Answer (score 4):

Well....

> I found hidden pictures in the edit box, and the showed these links.
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/9N7GH.png
>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeVlw.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTylz.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT88d.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkhhk.png

So

> Some of them had hidden imgur links that I followed and got to these links, but now I'm stuck 
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wnvx.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTylz.png
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuy6L.png

Comment: Jr cebonoyl unir gb cynl jvgu gur oevtugarff bs gur vzntr gung unf gur fgne. Vg ybbxf fvzvyne gb bar bs gur cerivbhf chmmyrf.

Comment: There are indeed *three* dead ends in this jungle maze.